# How to convert LocalDateTime to Date object in angular

Tags: angular5

I need to convert LocalDateTime to Date object in angular 5

How can I do that?

The date is in this format [2018,1,25,0,0]

Comment: Please include code you have tried, also look into the `date` pipe.

Comment: data['endDate'] = new Date(data['endDate']); In endDate i am getting the value as [ 2016, 1, 5, 0, 0 ]  - @HenslerSoftware

Comment: In the html using <p-calendar [required]="true" [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="key.endDate" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2000:2030" showButtonBar="true"> </p-calendar> @HenslerSoftware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date you are being provided is `[ 2016, 1, 5, 0, 0 ]` this is an array, so we can pull each item out and place it into the `new Date()` method.

See example below:-

```js
d = [ 2016, 1, 5, 0, 0 ];
endDate = new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2])
console.log(endDate);
```

I am also guessing that the 1 is January, if not, please remove the `- 1` inside the `new Date()` method.

So your code will look like:-

```js
let data = {
  endDate: [2016, 1, 5, 0, 0]
}

data['endDate'] = new Date(data['endDate'][0], data['endDate'][1] - 1, data['endDate'][2])

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(LocalDateTime)
```

where LocalDateTime is your local date time

Comment: I tried new Date(LocalDateTime) but the value is displaying as NaN/NaN/Nan - @Yasir Arafat

Comment: data['endDate'] = new Date(data['endDate']); In endDate i am getting the value as  [
                2016,
                1,
                5,
                0,
                0
            ]

Comment: In the html using   <p-calendar  [required]="true" [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="key.endDate"  [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2000:2030" showButtonBar="true">
              </p-calendar>   - @Yasir Arafat

Comment: Sorry for being late, I think you got the answer from Hensler Software